# MySQL search and replace apostrophe in serialized data

Tags: mysql, serialization, special-characters

I'm trying to find instances of a "|" (pipe) character in a field containing serialized data and replace it with a " ' " character (apostrophe).

I've tried this:

```
UPDATE postmeta SET meta_value = Replace(meta_value, '|', ''');
```

And this...

```
UPDATE postmeta SET meta_value = Replace(meta_value, '|', '"'"');
```

And this...

```
UPDATE postmeta SET meta_value = Replace(meta_value, '|', ''');
```

Also, this...

```
UPDATE postmeta SET meta_value = Replace(meta_value, '|', '\'');
```

Each result in errors.

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences

```
UPDATE postmeta SET meta_value = Replace(meta_value, '|', '''');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`UPDATE postmeta SET meta_value = Replace(meta_value, '|', "'");`